# How can I start developing IXI Modules?

Tags: iri-node, ixi

Looking at [MAM.ixi](https://github.com/iotaledger/MAM.ixi/blob/master/index.js) or [Snapshot.ixi](https://github.com/iotaledger/Snapshot.ixi/blob/master/index.js), I noticed that IXI Modules are written in Javascript but they are calling Java methods and using Java Classes by assignments like:

```
var Transaction = iri.controllers.TransactionViewModel;
var Address = iri.controllers.AddressViewModel;

Transaction.quietFromHash(IOTA.tangle, h)
```

Furthermore, the keywords `IOTA`, `API` and `IXICycle` can be used which probably has something to do with [this](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/5244112b00941ea58f07485d9289d576741d1f66/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/IXI.java#L250).

---

**Is there any documentation on this?

Is this IOTA-specific or a standardized technology and if it is, what's its name?

Are there tutorials or any other IXI Modules to look at?**

Comment: These questions are pretty related to this question:

[What exactly is “IOTA eXtensible Interface” (.ixi modules)?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1924/what-exactly-is-iota-extensible-interface-ixi-modules)

[What does an “Hello world!” IXI module look like?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/642/what-does-an-hello-world-ixi-module-look-like)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no official tutorials for the IXI modules yet.
You can write javascript according to the "JavaScript Nashorn engine" specifications.

This is a good place to learn more about it:
https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn%3A+Articles%2C+Documents%2C+Slides+and+Videos

Since the IOTA/iota object (Iota.java) class is exposed, you can use all functionality from IRI inside an IXI module by importing classes/objects using the methods you described

`var Transaction = iri.controllers.TransactionViewModel;`

Iota actually updated the Snapshot.ixi, which may now provide a better example